# Unable to populate detail block based on header block on a oracle form

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracleforms

I am facing a problem when i am trying to populate a detail block through the header block data in a `master-slave` or a `header-detail` form.

The header part consists of ***PoNo (PO Number)*** and an ***LOV (list of values)*** attached to it.The detail part consist of ***PO-details*** (items,rates,receipt-date,etc.) which resides in some other table and is inside the detail block.

Both blocks are related as `master-slave` using a `foreign key relationship`. What i am trying to do is select a ***PoNo*** from ***LOV*** and display detail in header as well as in detail section in one go but i am unable to do so.

When i select any ***PoNo*** using ***LOV*** a pop-up alert shows up asking ***'Do you want to save changes?'*** with three options of `'Yes'`,`'No'` or `'Cancel'`.

Note- I want to use ***execute-query*** to populate details.
      Both blocks are `database blocks`.

Help me understand what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If the steps you performed really are

- select PoNo from a LoV
- press Execute Query

then no wonder that you got that message - Forms detected that you entered a value into an item and *knows* that - if you perform Execute Query right now - those changes (i.e. value entered into PoNo) will be lost.

Therefore, your first step should be

- Enter Query mode

If you created everything with the Data Block Wizard, all master-detail triggers and procedures will be set and everything should work just fine.